# DMS Migration MongoDB source and RDS Postgres as destination

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, aws-dms

I want to start existing and ongoing replication from source MongoDB to destination RDS Postgres.

All the security network is done and successful.

1. RDS VPC and DMS VPC are connected using VPC peering, **target endpoint test connection status is successful**
2. DMS VPC IP is whitelisted in another AWS account MongoDB server, **source endpoint test connection status is successful**
3. In the Endpoint schemas section both database schemas are visible.

Created a DMS migration task to start the migration of one document of MongoDB to Postgres Database.

- Premigration assessments were successful.
- Empty scheme with the MongoDB schema name got created in PostgresDB.
- The table awsdms_apply_execution is also empty in Postgres DB.

But the task shows running with error and error, and cloud watch logs also show no error.